# Custom url_for for non rolling ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now if I create a URL for a model show action I simply call:

```
link_to model_instance
```

which creates something like this the when model is User and the id is 1:

```
/user/1
```

I like to customize that behavior without having to go through all instances in the codebase where a URL for such a model is generated. The motivation behind the change is avoiding rolling id's in the URL that lets anybody discover other entries by simply increasing the id. So something like

```
/user/88x11bc1200
```

Is there a place where I can simply override how a URL for selected models are generated? I am using RoR 4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are essentially two places you'll have to update.

**In the model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Override the to_param method
  def to_param
    # Whatever your field is called
    non_rolling_id
  end
end
```

**In the controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # Can't use `find` anymore, but will still come over as `id`
    @user = User.find_by_non_rolling_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```